# Referencing local package from external package

Tags: bazel

What label can be used to reference a local package from an external package's BUILD file?

Say I have package A, which is my top level package. In the WORKSPACE file of package A, I grab external package B, which I use the build_file argument to overlay a BUILD.bazel file onto.

A's cc_library rule does not actually depend on B.
The A.Tests rule, depends on A and on B. 
B has a dependency on A as well.

In the BUILD file that I defined for B, how do I reference A? No labels seemed to work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of B's BUILD file (specified with the build_file argument), I can reference A via this label: `@//<path_to_A>`

Answer (score 1):

If A.Tests depends on B (and A), and B also depends on A, why are A and B separate?

To answer your question, you need to create a third workspace C, declare both A and B as external workspaces, then A's targets can reference `@B//x:y` and B's targets can reference `@A//z:w`.

Comment: thanks. A and B are separate because a lot of other packages depend solely on A and don't need anything from B.